# I don't understand && in this JavaScript (JSX) Syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My understanding was that `&&` is an "and" operator. How can what follows `&&` in the code block return a boolean?

```
{accounts.length > 0 && (
        <View>
          {accounts.map((account) => (
            <AccountListItem
              key={account.mask}
              account={account}
              selectedAccount={selectedAccount}
              setSelectedAccount={setSelectedAccount}
            />
          ))}
        </View>
  )}
```

Comment: It doesn't return a boolean, it returns an element.

Comment: That's saying if the accounts.length > 0 then execute the following code, it's like a shorthand if statement

Comment: It returns an element and if the element exist it is truthy

Comment: FYI: although using `&&` works, it's often recommended to use a ternary that explicitly returns `null` if the condition is `false` instead. I can't recall the reasoning though...

Comment: @Slbox You can't use `accounts.length && <View />`, because even though `0` is falsy, it will render as "0" (numbers are converted to strings; `<>before{0}after</>` renders "before0after"). There's no particular reason not to use `accounts.length > 0 && <View />`, though, other than style preferences.

Comment: @LionelRowe ah yes, thank you! That's what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expr1 && expr2` [works like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND):

> If expr1 can be converted to `true`, returns expr2; else, returns expr1.

`expr1` is `accounts.length > 0`.

- If this is `false`, then it cannot be converted to `true`, so the whole expression evaluates to `false`.
- Otherwise, it is `true`, so the whole expression evaluates to `expr2`, which in our case is a `View` component.

In React, `false` renders nothing. You can verify this with the following minimal example:

```
const Test = () => <>before{false}after</>

ReactDOM.render(<Test />) // renders as "beforeafter"
```

In other words, in our example, if `accounts.length` is 0 then `false` is returned, rendering nothing; else, a `View` is returned, which is rendered.

Comment: Interesting. Why wouldn't I just use regular control flow?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "regular control flow"? If you mean an if statement, you can't use them inside react component rendering logic. If you mean a ternary operator, sure, you could use that, but this way is slightly more concise.

Answer (score 4):

(if this part is true) && (this part will execute)

[Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 1):

For && expression will not evaluate right side if left returns false so it's a short cut to doing following:

```
{accounts.length > 0 ? (
    <View>
      {accounts.map((account) => (
        <AccountListItem
          key={account.mask}
          account={account}
          selectedAccount={selectedAccount}
          setSelectedAccount={setSelectedAccount}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
):""}
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic operators are short circuit so if the left hand side of the expression of an and statement is false then the right hand side is not evaluated. It is a way of doing an if.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in JavaScript is coercible to boolean.

However, that doesn't really matter here. The result of the expression is inside of the `()` has no bearing on the action being taken.

`accounts.length > 0 &&` is a short circuit approach to make sure that the following action is taken only when accounts exist, presumably because `map` is used.

Evaluating the expression inside of `()` results in the `<View>` being rendered, and the return from evaluating that expression is never actually used, so regardless of what it is coerced into, it doesn't effect anything.

Comment: Everything in JavaScript can be considered truthy or falsey but that doesn't mean coercible to boolean.

Comment: @AdrianBrand - Yes, that is literally what that means. Please see [MDN's definition of truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20a%20truthy%20value,%2C%20undefined%20%2C%20and%20NaN%20).